# Wireless connection dropped after trying to ssh connection

Tags: wireless, ssh, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I have strange problem with wifi connection:
When raspberry is connected to my pc with ethernet cable I dont have any problem with ssh connection (by cable and wifi). 
But in case when cable isn't connected after boot i can ping raspberry, and when i try to connect by ssh BOOM - I can't (sometimes I can see byobu is launchded and I cannot do anythink) and then i cannot ping raspberry.

Raspberry Pi 2
OS: Ubuntu mate 16.04
Wifi dongle: TP-LINK TL-WN725N

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto enxb827eb61c62c
allow-hotplug enxb827eb61c62c
iface enxb827eb61c62c inet static
        address 11.0.0.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlx30b5c21096d1
allow-hotplug wlx30b5c21096d1
iface wlx30b5c21096d1 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

network={
        ssid="network1"
        psk="¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
}

network={
        ssid="network2"
        psk="¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
}
```

I think it's not problem with /interfaces because i tried couple of versions without any positive effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by Networkmanager or Wicd after uninstallation everything is ok.